# What is the current state of research on the representation of boolean functions using wavelets

Tags: boolean-functions

The harmonic representation of boolean functions such as XOR or AND has been studied in different course note lectures that can be found on Google.

http://cs.mcgill.ca/~hatami/comp760-2011/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/analysis-survey.pdf

What is the state of research on the representation of boolean functions using wavelets?

Comment: presumably there is a strong connection to [Fourier analysis](http://analysisofbooleanfunctions.org/) which is heavily researched eg by [O'Donnell](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/661/ryan-odonnell)...? maybe some type of basic bridge thm?